# VBA: How to remove rows with repeated value?

Tags: excel, vba

This my code, that I am trying to delete two row that would have `"-----------"` if two rows have that next to each other without spaces it needs to get deleted but if `"-----------"` had any value under or above then it shouldn't get deleted.

For some reason, it is giving me a `Run-time error` `1004` unable to get match property. Any assistance would be appreciated.  [image]

```
Sub Test()

      Dim WS As Worksheet, row1 As Long, row2 As Long, rng As Long, n As Long, nlast As Long, rw As Range

    For Each WS In Sheets

        nlast = WS.UsedRange.Rows(WS.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
        On Error GoTo NextWS

                 With WS
                     If WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

                    row1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("-----------", .Columns("D:L"), 0)
                    row2 = WorksheetFunction.Match("-----------", .Columns("D:L"), 0)
                        If .Range("D" & row1).Value = .Range("D" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("E" & row1).Value = .Range("E" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("F" & row1).Value = .Range("F" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("G" & row1).Value = .Range("G" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("H" & row1).Value = .Range("H" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("I" & row1).Value = .Range("I" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("J" & row1).Value = .Range("J" & row2).Value And _
                        .Range("K" & row1).Value = .Range("K" & row2).Value Then
          WS.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
          WS.Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete

   **ElseIf Row1 +1 <> "" and Row2 +1<>""
       else Row1 -1<>""  and Row2 -1<>""
               End if
                  End if** *Suede code* 


                 End If
                    End If
                End With
    NextWS:
            Err.Clear

            Next WS

          End Sub
```

Updated

```
   Sub Test()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Dim n As Long
   Dim nlast As Long

  For Each WS In Sheets


 nlast = WS.UsedRange.Rows(WS.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

 For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
 If WS.Cells(n, 4).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 5).Value = "-----------" And _
  WS.Cells(n, 6).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 7).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 8).Value = "-----------" And _
  WS.Cells(n, 9).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 10).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 11).Value = "-----------" Then

  ElseIf WS.Cells(n, 4).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 5).Value = "-----------" And _
  WS.Cells(n, 6).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 7).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 8).Value = "-----------" And _
  WS.Cells(n, 9).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 10).Value = "-----------" And WS.Cells(n, 11).Value = "-----------" Then

  WS.Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete

     End If
 Next n
 Next X
 Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Match only works with a one dimensional array not a two dimensional array, so only one column or row not multiple columns.  Also your row1 and row2 would be the same number as match only returns the first found.

Comment: Oh interesting, What should I use instead?? @ScottCraner

Comment: You will need to loop through the rows bottom to top and a second loop to loop through the columns comparing each cell with the one above and then delete each row.

Comment: @ScottCraner I updated my code, Is that what you meant? I think I am on the right track but I am not sure how do I code it to know to only delete when two of `-----------` are together without spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use AutoFilter() method and Areas property of Range object

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        With sh.Range("D1", sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="-----------"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For Each area In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                    If area.Count > 1 Then area.EntireRow.Delete
                Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End With
        Sh.AutoFilterMode = False
     Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim WS As Worksheet` `For Each WS In Sheets`                                                                         `Next WS` `End Sub` should this work?

Comment: Sorry it had to be "For Each sh In Worksheets", see edited code

Comment: Code in your last comment would do, too. But then you should also change all "sh" occurrencies to "WS".

Comment: Interesting, where is autoFilter coming from? its giving an error. Is it rng?

Comment: Yes sir you don't you have `.AutoFilter Field:=1,` that is not complying "Invalid use of property" pops up so then I tried `sh.Range.AutoFilter ` cuz it is a property of Range but still gave me an complying error sir.

Comment: I'm not by any PC so can't test it. Are you running the "exact" code as per my answer?

Comment: Oh woah that is very Impressive lol it works I know that. There is some syntax error. I try to make it work.

Comment: It gave a `Run time error 1004 autofilter method of range class failed` and yes I used the exact code

Comment: Before " .AutoFilter...." insert the following statement: MsgBox .Parent.Name & " - " & .Address   and see what it pops out

Comment: Then it seems not all of your worksheets have values in their column D to be filtered as for instance worksheet "CRITERIA" hasn't. You just put some check before AutoFiltering like for instance "If .Count > 1 Then ....here follows the AutoFilter code ... End If"

Comment: Oh yeahh, I forgot about "CRITERIA" there are some hidden sheets lol Okay I will create a check and if it doesn't work then I will be back to bother you lol

Comment: `If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then` I included this and it works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey, the macro was working fine before but now it is giving me an error saying Method `AutoFilterMode of object _ Worksheet failed`

Comment: When debugged this is highlighted `sh.AutoFilterMode = False`